# How do I transfer json objects into an excel file using python?

Tags: python, json, excel, pandas

How do I transfer json objects into an excel file using python?

I am currently working on a project to make a database of professors.
I was able to loop through each link in a for loop and get such data:

```
{"total": 1, "offset": 0, "data": [{"authorId": "118985833", "name": "Krystle K. Madrid"}]}

{"total": 1, "offset": 0, "data": [{"authorId": "107707217", "name": "S. N. Kirnon"}]}

{"total": 5, "offset": 0, "data": [{"authorId": "121754802", "name": "Jason L. Jarvis"}, {"authorId": "143879405", "name": "J. Jarvis"}, {"authorId": "145088127", "name": "J. Jarvis"}, {"authorId": "31259897", "name": "J. W. Jarvis"}, {"authorId": "38535862", "name": "J. D. Jarvis"}]}
```

I am trying to find a way to make a excel file with columns AuthorID and Name.
Please let me know if anyone can help me how I can do this using Python.

Comment: It's not clear what your code is supposed to indicate. Are these three separate dictionaries that you have created?

Comment: df = pd.read_excel(r"C:\Users\Maro\Desktop\ProfessorList.xlsx", sheet_name='sheet1')

list1 = list(df['First Name'])
list2 = list(df['Last Name'])
list3 = []      
list4 = []


while True:
    try:
        list3.append("https://api.semanticscholar.org/graph/v1/author/search?query="+list1.pop(0)+"+"+list2.pop(0))
    except IndexError:
        break

for i in range(5):
    url = list3[i]
    res = requests.get(url)
    res.raise_for_status()
    soup= BeautifulSoup(res.text,"lxml")
    datas = soup.get_text()
    print(datas)

Comment: That is my python code, so i have a for loop that will make a dictionary every time it iterates. 
Since I am trying this out the loop has range 5, but once the code works it will be more than 500. 
I am trying to find a way to make a excel file that will have a column authorID and name

Comment: Ok, that clears things up, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For example, you could do something like the following:

```
dics = [
    {"total": 1, "offset": 0, "data": [{"authorId": "118985833", "name": "Krystle K. Madrid"}]},
{"total": 1, "offset": 0, "data": [{"authorId": "107707217", "name": "S. N. Kirnon"}]},
{"total": 5, "offset": 0, "data": [{"authorId": "121754802", "name": "Jason L. Jarvis"}, {"authorId": "143879405", "name": "J. Jarvis"}, {"authorId": "145088127", "name": "J. Jarvis"}, {"authorId": "31259897", "name": "J. W. Jarvis"}, {"authorId": "38535862", "name": "J. D. Jarvis"}]}
]

df = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['AuthorID','Name'])

for d1 in dics:
    for d2 in d1["data"]:
        df = pd.concat([df,
                        pd.DataFrame({"AuthorID":[d2["authorId"]],
                                      "Name":[d2["name"]]})],
                        ignore_index=True)
```

The result:

```
    AuthorID               Name
0  118985833  Krystle K. Madrid
1  107707217       S. N. Kirnon
2  121754802    Jason L. Jarvis
3  143879405          J. Jarvis
4  145088127          J. Jarvis
5   31259897       J. W. Jarvis
6   38535862       J. D. Jarvis
```

A similar loop with the same result:

```
for d1 in dics:
    d_new = {"AuthorID":[d2["authorId"] for d2 in d1["data"]],
            "Name":[d2["name"] for d2 in d1["data"]]}
    df = pd.concat([df,pd.DataFrame(d_new)],ignore_index=True)
```

Here's a one line solution:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"AuthorID":[d2["authorId"] for d1 in dics for d2 in d1["data"]],
            "Name":[d2["name"] for d1 in dics for d2 in d1["data"]]})
```

Comment: It worked!
Thank you so much!! I really appreciate it.
You saved my life

Comment: Glad to hear it, and glad to help

Answer (score 0):

With [Pandas](https://pypi.org/project/pandas/):

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
  [
    data
    for link in links
    for data in link["data"]
  ]
)
df.rename(columns={"authorId": "AuthorId", "name": "Name"}).to_csv("data.csv")
```